# How to build PythonQT on Mac

Tags: python, qt, pythonqt

I'm trying to build QT app with python embedded by PythonQT but stuck at building PythonQT.

Here is my environment and what I did:

- mac os 10.15
- python 3.8.5 installed by homebrew
- python-dev-tools installed by pip
- QT 5.15
- download PythonQT source code from https://github.com/MeVisLab/pythonqt
- open PythonQT.pro file in QT Creator (I don't have qmake command available globaly)

I don't have Headers path under /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/, so in python.prf file, I did the following modification:

- change include path: INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
- change Lib path: LIBS += -F/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks -framework Python

then:

- right click project root and select Run qmake
- right click project root and select build

I got this error:

```
No rule to make target /Users/xxx/Applications/Qt/5.15.0/clang_64/lib/libQt5UiTools_debug.a', needed by `../../lib/libPythonQt_QtAll-Qt5-Python3.8_d.3.2.0.dylib'.  Stop.
```

If I use the original python.prf file, build with error the Python.h file not found.

Answer (score 0):

The default build configuration is Debug, change it to Release resolve the issue.
Build debug version requires some more twist according to the official doc: https://mevislab.github.io/pythonqt/Building.html